# Where is the "Debug -> Exceptions..." menu in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for the first time, and having trouble finding the classic "Debug -> Exceptions..." menu, present in VS 2013 and earlier. Where can I access this menu now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now in "Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings", which brings up a menu in a new "Exception Settings" tab, typically at the bottom of the IDE (such as Error List, Output, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the keyboard shortcut: Ctl + Alt + E